# How to get paramter from url and check in view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this url:

```
http://test.dev/search?publishing_types[]=Selling&priceFrom=0&priceTo=300000&areaFrom=0&areaTo=300000&floors[]=2&yearFrom=1900&yearTo=2017
```

Now what i want in view is something like this:

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="preventUncheck" name="publishing_types[]" id="toggle-on{{ $index }}" value="{{ $prop_type }}"  @if (publishg_types== Selling) {!! "checked" !!} @endif >

  <input type="checkbox" class="preventUncheck" name="publishing_types[]" id="toggle-on{{ $index }}" value="{{ $prop_type }}"  @if (publishg_types== Reng) {!! "checked" !!} @endif >
```

So what i want is to check in checkbox if `publishing_types == Selling` and/or `publishing_types == Rent`   from url to check that checkboxes

Comment: You can simply use `$request['NAME']` if you passed it to your method otherwise you have to pass it

Comment: in view i get this error then Undefined variable: request

Comment: Use the `request()`-helper function with `request('publishing_types')`

Comment: Yeah in the view you have to use the `request()` function like @Sebastian said

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request()` helper like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="preventUncheck" name="publishing_types[]" id="toggle-on{{ $index }}" value="{{ $prop_type }}"  @if (in_array('Selling', request(publishg_types)) {!! "checked" !!} @endif >

<input type="checkbox" class="preventUncheck" name="publishing_types[]" id="toggle-on{{ $index }}" value="{{ $prop_type }}"  @if (in_array('Reng', request(publishg_types)) {!! "checked" !!} @endif >
```